# XAMl version Syntax in Windows Store apps and Windows Phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

AS known in Windows Store apps and Windows Phone apps i can write my views using XAML ,
so i have aquestion:

are XAMl of every type of apps is based on specific version of silverlight?
or it is isolated versionof XAML . for example is there XAMl for Windows Store apps which is not aversion of SIlver Light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: yes, you're using XAML *pretty much* the same way as you're using it in Silverlight, for both platforms.

A bit longer answer: XAML for Windows Store apps is a bit of different beast than for Windows Phone. For Windows Store apps, XAML is basically compiles to the unmanaged code. For WP (7 and 8) it's mostly the Silverlight as of ver. 3 with some of difference (much poorer reflection support in WP, for example). For a full list of differences between standard Silverlight and WP version, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28VS.95%29.aspx).

But the biggest difference is that XAML for WP still belongs to managed code. This means XAML for WP and W8 are not binary compatible. But the good thing is that they're sharing biggest part of the controls. Microsoft has a couple of articles describing differences, similarities, and possible approaches to reuse the code between these 2 platforms, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714088%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: WP7.0 was based on SL3 but WP7.1 (aka 7.5/Mango) actually pulls in most of SL4 which is useful for Tap events etc.